# Edit Payment Method after Invoice is created (Magento CE 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, payment

is there an extension or way to change the payment method after an order is completed or invoiced?

We want to process our invoices to our tax consultants and they do some automated stuff with it (compare paypal account exports to orders with paypal as payment method...), but some of our invoices have errors, e.g. because the customer ordered with bank pre-payment but pays at our local store (and some other constellations) so I have to correct the payment method.

Is there any way to correct these things, even if the order is completed?

I've had a look at https://www.iwdagency.com/extensions/magento-edit-order-manager.html but it creates a new invoice number for every change (and I didn't get behind, if it cancels the old invoice) so its not perfectly what I need.